# Less doesn't work on compiled client-side

Tags: less

I have a very simple html file in which I am using less to preprocess css. For this test, I have used standalone html file and latest firefox browser.

HTML file is as below:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="category.less" />
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/1.7.0/less.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="text">Hello there!!</div>
</body>
```

My *category.less* file is as below:

```
.setColor(){
  @colorx:"yellow";
}
.text{
    .setColor();
    color: @colorx;
    font-size:20px;
}
```

I have developed this example on the basis of [this example from less documentation](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-as-functions-feature).

My problem is when I run the file, ***color*** css property is not applied at all.

In Firebug, it looks like this:

```
.text {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

However, when I parse same *less* code through online less preprocessors, I do get desired output. I have tried [this compiler](http://winless.org/online-less-compiler) , [this compiler](http://www.freeformatter.com/less-compiler.html#ad-output) and [this compiler](http://lesstester.com/).

Worth noting that [this compiler](http://leafo.net/lessphp/editor.html) gave same output as my code (without color property).

Comment: `"yellow"` is not valid CSS color value. The correct one is [`yellow`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#html4).

Comment: I tried, red, blue, and even hex codes. This was just an example. But thanks for correction.

Comment: Well, this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7pTxS/) shows your code actually works. So I don't see any reason why it would not on your side apart from "yellow" typo. Unless a browser has a problem accessing either file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the differences in output you're seeing are due to these compilers using different versions of the LESS spec. <s>Previous versions</s> current versions of LESS (thanks @seven-phases-max) allow variables created in mixins to be used throughout the whole document ('global scope').

You've created the `@colorx` variable inside of a mixin. To make your code work in a compiler using version 1.4.x, you either need to set your `@colorx` variable outside the mixin, so it has global scope, or apply the colour to `.text` by using the mixin.

Here's an example [demonstrating variable scope LESS in a compiler (currently) running an older compiler](http://leafo.net/lessphp/editor.html#//%20Input%20LESS%20here,%20strike%20%27Ctrl%7CCommand+Enter%27%20to%20compile.%0A%0A@var1%3a%20red;%0A%0A.a-mixin%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20@var2%3a%20blue;%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20color%3a%20@var2;%0A%7D%0A%0A.ex1%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20color%3a%20@var1;%20%20%20%0A%7D%0A%0A.ex2%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20color%3a%20@var2;%0A%7D%0A%0A.ex3%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20.a-mixin%28%29;%0A%7D%0A%0A) 
So I guess you have a couple of options.

Option one, keeping using the old compiler and change your mixin to this:

```
.setColor(){
    @colorx:"yellow";
    color: @colorx;
}

.text {
    .steColor();
    font-size:20px;
}
```

Or, drop set colour all together, and declare the `@colorx:"yellow";` variable in the body of your less file.

Or lastly, as @seven-phases-max has pointed out, your code works in the current versions of the compiler, so you could switch to a more up-to-date compiler and use your code as-is.

Comment: Less variables defined in a mixin are exposed to the outer scope actually (see [docs](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-as-functions-feature)). It's just the lessphp compiler that does not properly support this Less feature.

Comment: That's interesting. So @Nis has followed the docs correctly, but some compilers are doing it wrong?

Comment: Yes, this feature was added in Less 1.4.x but certain compilers (lessphp, dotless) are stalled near Less version 1.3.3, being behind ~1.5 years from now.